# why BitBlt() is slower in python compared to C++?

Tags: python, c++, image, gdi+, win32gui

I am trying to use `BitBlt()` function to copy the bitmap data.

When I use the python `win32ui/win32gui` `API` the average time it takes is coming around 30 ms, while the same `API` when I call using C++, the average time comes around 10-15 ms.

So I am wondering, what could be the reason for the this behavior?

Thanks

EDIT : Here is the snippet :

python :

```
hdesktop = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

# create a device context
desktop_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hdesktop)
img_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(desktop_dc)

# create a memory based device context
mem_dc = img_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()

# create a bitmap object
screenshot = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
screenshot.CreateCompatibleBitmap(img_dc, width, height)
oldbmp = mem_dc.SelectObject(screenshot)


# copy the screen into our memory device context
mem_dc.BitBlt((destUpLeftX, destUpLeftY), (width, height), img_dc, (srcUpLeftX, srcUpLeftY),win32con.SRCCOPY)

mem_dc.SelectObject(oldbmp)

win32gui.DeleteObject(screenshot.GetHandle())
img_dc.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hdesktop, desktop_dc)
mem_dc.DeleteDC()
```

C++ :

```
HDC hwindowDC=GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
HDC hwindowCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);


// create a bitmap
HBITMAP hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hwindowDC, width, height);
LOG(LOG_DBG, "before SelectObject");

// SAVE OLD BITMAP
HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow); //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow


BitBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, destUpLeftX, destUpLeftY, width, height, hwindowDC, srcUpLeftX, srcUpLeftY, SRCCOPY);

SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hOldBmp);
DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC); 
DeleteObject(hbwindow);

// RELEASE WINDOW DC
ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hwindowDC);
```

Comment: That is strange indeed. Are you sure the copied bitmaps have the same size and both calls succeed? Can you show the code for both (including how you measured the time)?

Comment: Different languages do different things, and implements things differently as well too. And you have to remember that Python is an *interpreted* language while C++ is a *compiled* language. That is probably the reason here (the Python call has to pass more layers).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Normally yes, but here the actual work is being done by Windows, not Python or C++, and I cannot imagine that Python has a 15-20 ms overhead for a simple function call.

Comment: @nwp yes the size is same and both calls succeed. I have edited my question with the code snippet. To verify the timing I use a for loop for 1000 times, and push the time in a list or vector respectively, and finally I print the average and the whole list/vector.

Comment: @Rahul are you comparing the entire runtime of the above snippets, or only the specific call to BitBlt()?

Comment: @Bilkokuya No, I am just comparing BitBlt(). Although I tried comparing complete block also, but compare to BitBlt(), other calls are very insignificant in timing.

Comment: I ran a quick test but I couldn't find a significant difference. Make sure width and height are the same in both tests. I am thinking the two applications have different DPI settings, and one of them is seeing a smaller screen. `BitBlt` on a fullscreen is the most expensive part, it's about 5 milliseconds in C++ (depending on screen size and video card)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani can you share your test code ?

Comment: My code is similar to yours. You should show the values for `destUpLeftX, destUpLeftY, width, height, srcUpLeftX, srcUpLeftY`

Comment: I wonder why nobody asked - how are you measuring the time in C++ vs. Python?